# Is it possible to build a "DIY" quantum memory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-computer, fiber-optics, non-linear-optics, cryogenics

I am currently working on a home project which is a computer which will be capable of doing basic quantum computations (my first goal is a random-number generator) based on optical devices. Nowadays I am searching for ways to make a small quantum memory (I would be very happy with even 1 qubit). Then my problem rises: How could I create a qubit which I could store information with? I came across various publications about the usefulness of doped Yttrium orthovanadate crystals at cryogenic temperatures etc... so I am aware of several methods but I would like to find a bit easier method if it is possible. If you know any easier way please help me out a bit.
 My current capabilities(if it helps):

> - Cryogenic temperatures for small volumes (with [peltier cooling](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.1610810))
> - Manufacturing integrated devices on silicon wafers (with photolithographic methods)
> - Synthesizing CdSe, carbon and graphene quantum dots

But it's obvious that I can't handle single atoms or manipulate things precisely in a nanometer scale. If it's absolutely necessary, I can use a scanning electron microscope (Obviously it is not mine).Note: my question is not only for optical devices.

Comment: I'm not sure that quantum memory has been achieved by anyone at this point... Maybe storage has, but not retrieval afaik. I look forward to the answers...

Comment: One thing other peoples' projects have taught me: It's ***always*** possible to DIY, but the questions are whether you need corrosive or expensive chemicals or other dangerous substances, years of building, years of learning, or thousands of dollars of workshop equipment. (usually not more than thousands, e.g. it's very rarely tens of thousands)

Answer (score 0):

Your basic idea of building a quantum computer might be a little ambitious for any one individual, but I'm not sure what other tools you would have access to, so it might be plausible. However, you would certainly need an advanced laser manipulation system to get any data from the memory, since extraction of precise enough data from it.

Even if you are simply using a two-qubit system for your calculations, facilitating interactions and entanglement between the atoms would probably require more precise machinery than it sounds like you have in your possession. However if you manage to do it on your own, that would be really cool.